# JQuery prints undefined instead of data from JSON array

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm developing a PhoneGap application with JQuery and am using AJAX to send and receive JSON data from a PHP file. For one part of my app, I would like a user to click a button and for it to display a list of vacancies.
The JSON returned looks like this:

```
{"Vacancy":{"vacancyID":"1","projectCode":"ABCD01","title":"a title","supervisor":"Some name","description":"A description of the project vacancy","course":"Computer Science"}},
{"Vacancy":{"vacancyID":"6","projectCode":"ABCD02","title":"some title","supervisor":"some supervisor","description":"description of sorts","course":"Computer Science"}}
```

I'm able to get the above showing in an alert, but when I attempt to print it, it instead outputs:

```
action undefined -
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Here is the script I have used to attempt to print it out in my html file:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //load JSON data
        var output = $('#vacancies');
        $("#btnVacancy").click(function() {
            var data = {"action": "test" };

            $.ajax({
                //where php file is
                url: "http://localhost/helloworld/api.php",
                    //using GET in php file
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { type:"getV", pCourse:"Computer Science" },
                    ContentType: "application/json",
                    success: function(response) {
                        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                            //data has been loaded
                            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                            var vacancy = '<br>'
                            //project code
                            + '<h4>' + i + " " + item.projectCode + ' - ' + '</h4>'
                            // project title
                            + '<p>' + item.title + '<br>'
                            // project supervisor
                            + item.supervisor + '<br>'
                            //project description
                            + item.description + '</p>';

                        output.append(vacancy);
                    });
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

My question is why is the information correct in the alert, but undefined once printed out?

Comment: Can you post exactly how are you getting in success call back?

Comment: And did you try `item.Vacancy.projectCode`

Comment: 1st thing, `$.each(data, function(i, item) {` here `data` is not an array or your JSON data, `item.projectCode` will always be undefined.

Comment: @MokshShah does this mean you want me to add the PHP code?

Comment: @adeneo tried it just there, no longer prints anything :( Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Rachael, Nope not php code, but just verify your ajax call, in success call back, simply write `console.log(response)` and verify the result in browser's console, and put that exact result here.

Comment: @MokshShah sorry, I'm an idiot haha. When I do that it comes up with "Array [ Array[2] ]" in Firefox

Comment: Yep I knew it (of course about : Its an array :P ), post your code, or even my answer should work in your case.

Comment: @MokshShah I ended up changing my code by following a youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLCxRtHW4x8) and this works for my purposes. Thank you for all your help, regardless

Answer (score 1):

1st thing, $.each(data, function(i, item) { here data is not an array or your JSON data, item.projectCode will always be undefined.

If your JSON is something like this, then bellow code should work in your case:

```
[{"Vacancy":{"vacancyID":"1","projectCode":"ABCD01","title":"a title","supervisor":"Some name","description":"A description of the project vacancy","course":"Computer Science"}},
{"Vacancy":{"vacancyID":"6","projectCode":"ABCD02","title":"some title","supervisor":"some supervisor","description":"description of sorts","course":"Computer Science"}}]
```

```js
var responseData = [{"Vacancy":{"vacancyID":"1","projectCode":"ABCD01","title":"a title","supervisor":"Some name","description":"A description of the project vacancy","course":"Computer Science"}},{"Vacancy":{"vacancyID":"6","projectCode":"ABCD02","title":"some title","supervisor":"some supervisor","description":"description of sorts","course":"Computer Science"}}]

$.each(responseData,function(i,item){
  alert(item.Vacancy.projectCode);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tried this, but it no longer prints anything out

Comment: In that case, you need to post your JSON result

Answer (score 0):

**Weak points of your solution:**

> 1. `$.each(data, function(i, item) {` if it's not an array it will be undefined.
> 2. `dataType: "json"` in `GET` doesn't mean that your `.php` is returning back data with the same header. In this case `JSON.parse()` will be necessary.
> 3. You are alerting `alert(JSON.stringify(response));` but you are appending `output.append()` the iterated element, from the Test Driven Development point of view this is a bad practice. Test same format of data that you are trying to work with.